# C++ constructor confusion

Tags: c++, constructor

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject(para1);
```

In Java I can always do this while switching to C++ it gives me an error:conversion from ‘MyObject*’ to non-scalar type ‘MyObject’ requested.

It seems the way to fix it is `MyObject* obj = new MyObject(para1);`.

What if I want the object itself rather than the pointer to the object?

Would `MyObject obj(para1);`be the only way that works for me?

Since I'm switching from Java to C++, I also wonder:

```
MyObject* obj1 = new MyObject(para1);
```

If I print out the value of `obj1`, it would be an address.

```
MyObject obj2(para1);
```

What would be the printed-out value for `obj2`?

Comment: Since you're switching from Java to C++, the first thing you should learn is that you don't need `new` every time. In fact, you should strive to keep that to a minimum.

Comment: If you're serious about learning C++, you should a) forget about Java, b) forget about pointers and `new`, c) start by reviewing the C++ object model and *storage classes*, and finally d) review the standard library features with regard to containers, algorithms and RAII management classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would `MyObject obj(para1);`be the only way that works for me?

Yes, that is the normal way.

> What would be the printed-out value for obj2?

If you haven't overloaded the correct operator, you would get a compiler error.  *You* define how your object is printed, using a function with the following signature:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const MyObject & obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

In some cases<sup>*</sup>, you can also do:

```
MyObject obj = MyObject(para1);
```

Unlike in Java, objects don't inherit a `toString` method from some base class.  So you can't print out the value of `obj2` unless you've defined a mechanism to do so.  The standard way is to overload `operator<<`:

```
class MyObject
{
public:
    int x;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MyObject &obj)
{
    os << obj.x;
    return os;
}

...

MyObject obj;
obj.x = 42;
std::cout << obj << "\n";
```

---

<sub>* Namely, if the class has a public copy constructor.</sub>

Comment: Only if `MyObject` is copyable.  A lot of types aren't.  (And I'd have added adjectives like "useless" or "irrelevant" to `toString`:-).)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the new operator returns a pointer to the object.  To get the object, you need to dereference the pointer using the * operator (e.g. *obj).

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much answered your own question. If you don't want a pointer then don't use new.. If you're new to c++ and memory management, and you really do need to use a pointer, I'd strongly suggest using a smart pointer (e.g. boost::shared_ptr) instead of a raw pointer..

As for the second question, it depends on what you mean by print out. You can't just print out an object, but you can call a method that knows how to print that object out. You'd have to define this method of course. Something like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyObject& rhs)
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems the way to fix it is MyObject* obj = new MyObject(para1);.

Yes. The result of new is always a pointer to an object.
Note in C++ it is very rare to use RAW pointers (you normally put a pointer into a smart pointer so that it will get correctly deleted).

> What if I want the object itself rather than the pointer to the object?

```
MyObject obj(para1)   // Creates an normal automatic object
                      // The destructor for this obect is automatically called
                      // When the object goes out of scope (even when exceptions are thrown)
```

> I also wonder:

```
MyObject* obj1 = new MyObject(para1);
```

> If I print out the value of obj1, it would be an address.

If you print this out:

```
std::cout << obj1;  // print the address (normally).

std::cout << (*obj1); // Will print the object/
                      // Assuming you have defined the output operator.

MyObject obj2(para1);
std::cout << obj2;    // Again prints the object
                      // Assuming you have defined the output operator.
std::cout << &obj2;   // prints the address.
```

Answer (score -1):

Think about the Pointer-Operator `->` or `(*obj).func()`

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: the "New" operator creates a Pointer to an object. You cannot acces an element created by new with the single "." operator like in java, you have to dereference it (with *) or by using the "->", that is short for dereferencing and calling the objects member. If you want to use somethink like in java, you have to use this operator